# Image file stored in original input format in place of mentioned format

Tags: javax.imageio

Hi I am taking input image in any format from browser and passing it to server.At server site added saveImage() method for storing image in .jpeg format but it stored same as original format which accepted in browser.

Here is my code

```
public boolean saveImage(byte[] byteImage, String transactionId) {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage);
    try {
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
        File imageFile = new File(filePath+ transactionId + ".jpeg");
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", imageFile);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error===" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! Your code looks reasonable to me. And I don't see a question mark anywhere in your question. Is there any problem? If that's the case, then please update the question with a description of the problem, and any stack trace or error message you get.

Comment: I want to store image as .jpeg format but when I give input as .png image it store as it with .png format.It should be .jpeg

Comment: I don't see how that can happen from the code you have posted, so I suggest debugging, and probably look elsewhere in your code. Some things that *might* be worth looking into though, is: There's no guarantee that `ImageIO.read(in)` will return in a non-`null` image. You might want to add a null check before proceeding. Also, `ImageIO.write(...)` returns a `boolean`. You should probably return that value, rather than always `true`.